# SSRS Matrix header repeat on each page (but outside of group to show every header from ds?)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a Matrix which I am trying to get a specific header to repeat on each page.  To keep it simple it looks something like this:

```
|        |  Months  |
|Division|          |
| Name   |   Sales  |

--- new page for each division ---
```

If I include the [Month] columns inside the Division group, it only shows the [Months] that have activity for that [Division].  For each page (per [Division]) I want to show all active [Months] within the dataset, not just that particular [Division].

So I tried creating a new row above, OUTSIDE of the [Division] group.  This worked great for the first page, but I cannot get it to repeat on each page.

Is there a way to somehow set a Matrix row as a header for each instance/page of that tablix in the report?

Or

Show every [Month] from the dataset, inside of the [Division] group, and not just the active [Months] inside the [Division]?

Hopefully that makes sense, if not I will try my hardest to explain better.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207045.aspx

Under "To Display a static row or column on multiple pages"

Thanks